# How to interpret sig. p-value in 1000 simulated datasets?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, simulation, statistical-power

it's a simple question but I'm lacking in the department of statistics, so could someone please explain to me how to interpret my p-value from the power analysis?
Here is what I've done (using R):
1.  Ran my original sem model, then I specified a population model by assigning the parameter values from the original model.
2.  Created a misspecified model, with 2 paths flipped.
3.  Drew a 1000 datasets of size n from the hypothetical population. 
4.  Fit misspecified model to each of the 1000 datasets.
5.  "R" yielded mean p-value < 0.05 = 0.047.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what the p-value you derived from each of your 1000 simulated data-sets represents?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the question. I asked "R" to record chi square values, degrees of freedom and p-values for each of the misspecified model fitted to the 1000 datasets, so I got 1000 p-values. Then I asked R to give me the mean for p < 0.05, and it gave me the value of 0.047. That means that there are 47 unique results out of 1000 datasets (so, approximately in 5% of simulated databases), right? So, i get that but I'm not sure how to interpret it. Does it mean that it's the probability for type 1 or 2 error? Does misspecified model have the right to exist? It's a power analysis. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen exact same question here but they got non-significant values, so I can't figure out how sig. values are different. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this sort of thing by simulation you usually generate simulated data-sets under a variety of alternative hypotheses and fit your model. The number of times it rejects the null is then the power against that specific alternative. If you do it on the null you will get back your chosen alpha which is the power to reject the null. In your case it is slightly different as you do not have an alternative, just the null, so I am not too surprised you are getting back a value close to your alpha.

You may need to think again about what you are trying to do and then ask a fresh question about the best way to approach it.